# How to calculate this area?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For didactic purposes I want to calculate the area of the set $\{z+\frac{z^2}{2} : z\in \mathbb{C} \wedge |z| \leq 1\}$ in the complex plane. This is the image of the unit disk under the map $z\rightarrow \frac {z^2} 2 +z$. Making use of the polar coordinates and the result of

```
Expand[(r Cos[\[Theta]] + I*r Sin[\[Theta]])^2/2 + r Cos[\[Theta]] + I*r Sin[\[Theta]]]
```

> `r Cos[\[Theta]] + 1/2 r^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 + I r Sin[\[Theta]] +  I r^2 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]] - 1/2 r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2`

, I write down that domain as a parametric region

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{r Cos[\[Theta]] + 1/2 r^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2 - 
1/2 r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2, r Sin[\[Theta]] + r^2 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]]},
 {{\[Theta], 0,  2 \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 1}}]
```

Unfortunately,

```
RegionMeasure[reg]
```

> The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation.

in two hours. Is there a way to calculate it with Mathematica? I am interested in the exact result.

Comment: It would be helpful to know your Mathematica version

Comment: @mikado: 13.2 on Windows 10. My comp is not powerful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just use [`ParametricRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion) directly without switching to polar coordinates?

```
reg = With[{z=x+I y},
    ParametricRegion[
        {
            ComplexExpand[ReIm[z+z^2/2]], 
            ComplexExpand[Abs[z]^2 <= 1]
        },
        {x, y}
    ]
]
```

> ParametricRegion[{{x + x^2/2 - y^2/2, y + x y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {x, y}]

```
RegionPlot[reg]
```

> [image]

Approximate result:

```
RegionMeasure[reg,WorkingPrecision->MachinePrecision]
```

> 4.71239

Exact result:

```
area = RegionMeasure[reg];//AbsoluteTiming
area
```

> {0.578509, Null}

> (3 Pi)/2

Check:

```
area //N
```

> 4.71239